# Bluetooth connection problems, win 8.1, connected but no audio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, connection, headphones

Bluetooth headphones pair with windows 8.1 laptop then say connected then just go back to "paired" status.  When and if they do connect to the laptop, the status is connected but there is no audio coming out of the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION 1/2: CONNECT BLUETOOTH EAR BUDS TO COMPUTER

1. Create a system restore point. (Right click Start menu->Left click System->->L Click ....System Protection->L Click Create->Give a name->L Click Create)
2. Went to computer manufacturers website. (lenovo.com in this case)
3. Downloaded the device driver software for the Bluetooth functionality.
4. Uninstalled ALL of the Bluetooth drivers in Device Manager and checked off the option          ....to delete the Bluetooth Software.  (this does not delete the recently downloaded software.)
5. Run the downloaded software that was downloaded from the manufacturers website to ....reinstall the drivers for Bluetooth.
6. Restart the Computer.
7. Pair the device (sony MDR-XB50BS headphones in this case).

At this point the device was connected but no sound was coming out of the earbuds.

SOLUTION 2/2: GET SOUND FROM EAR BUDS

8. Open Control Panel
9. Using small icon view choose the option for sound.
10. Right-Click on Headphones and choose Set as Default Device (the speakers will play ....sound when the headphones are not connected but the headphones will play the sound ....when the headphones ARE connected.)

Now my headphones connect to the computer automatically when turned on and play sound!

THANK YOU!